# How to implement an IS-A relationship in Express with Sequelize for Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I wish to implement an IS-A relationship. I've been reading https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#one-to-one-associations and think that I should use a belongs to relationship.For example, let's say I have Orthopedic which IS-A Doctor. Would this be the right way to go about it?

```
Orthopedic.belongsTo(models.Doctor, {
    name: 'id',
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
 });
```

The models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Orthopedic = sequelize.define('Orthopedic', {
        specialization: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
    });


    return Orthopedic;
};

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Doctor = sequelize.define('Doctor', {
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        age: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
    });


    return Doctor;
};
```

Comment: It seems like you are confusing model declaration (`name`, `type` and `primaryKey` keys) with association declaration (`foreginKey` key). Can you post the mode definition of both `Orthopedic` and `Doctor`? I'll suggest the association declaration that fits.

Comment: @AntonDrukh, I've added example model definitions now! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize documentation for `belongsTo` association:

> BelongsTo associations are associations where the foreign key for the one-to-one relation exists on the source model.
>
> A simple example would be a Player being part of a Team with the foreign key on the player.

```
class Player extends Model {}
Player.init({/* attributes */}, { sequelize, modelName: 'player' });
class Team extends Model {}
Team.init({/* attributes */}, { sequelize, modelName: 'team' });

Player.belongsTo(Team); // Will add a teamId attribute to Player to hold the primary key value for Team
```

Applying to your case, you'd need to add

```
Orthopedic.belongsTo(models.Doctor)
```

Note that this will add a `doctorId` attribute to the `Orthopedic` model which is not defined in the original model definition.

The difference between this and your original suggestion is that the options argument relates to the association, and should not define attributes of a model.